# Restore Gentoo grub and Windows 8

Tags: linux, mount, windows, grub, gentoo

I know there a many questions of this type. But I readed almost all
and I haven't clear what are gonna do to solve.

Recently I've finished the Gentoo's installation, but before that I had W8. When I finished the Gentoo's installation, only started it Gentoo.

To solve the above situation, I started with a USB live with Ubuntu, and I installed the boot-repair, but this screwed up the thing, thing got worse; because then I reboot my computer and just appear me the grub rescue screen.

Below is my HDD partition

[image]

How can solve this through Gentoo or another distro similar?
Thank you, and sorry if this question is similar than other.

Answer (score 1):

Just from the grub rescue command line I find [this](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/) very useful but it sounds to me like you will need a reinstall of grub. I would say run a `grub2-install` on `sda` then `emerge os-prober` so that grub can find Windows and then update your grub file.

But we will need more information if Gentoo does not detect windows.

Comment: I've repaired the grub menu! But still doesn't appear my windows partition.
I followed the instructions of this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/564496/trying-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-14-10-with-windows-10-last-one-not-detected but doesn't works 

About your link, doesn't work the instructions that have wrote it.